# Is it possible when comparing two strings with '==' returns true but return false with '.equals' in java

Tags: java

I'm bit confused about the difference between == and .equals, I been searching for answers but still not quite clear. So, I'm wondering is there an example code can demonstrate that when comparing two strings, == and .equals return different results.

Comment: No counterexample exists. `==` being true will always imply `equals()` being true by definition.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two distinct questions here. There isn't an example where `==` returns true but `equals` returns false. That is not possible. Because (as an optimization) `equals` checks for reference identity. But even if it did not, it does test for value identity (and that would be the same).

However, there are lots of examples where `==` returns false but `equals` returns true. Because `==` tests references. One trivial example,

```
String a = "A";
String b = new String(a);
System.out.println(a == b);
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```